# How do I apply the Kotlin jvm plugin from another custom plugin?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, groovy

I'm trying to integrate Kotlin into our build system, which uses custom plugins to encapsulate the set of plugins needed for a particular build archetype. Example:

```
import org.gradle.api.plugins.GroovyPlugin
import org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin
import {our internal Java path}.OurBasePlugin

class OurJavaPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.plugins.apply OurBasePlugin

        project.plugins.apply JavaPlugin
        project.plugins.apply GroovyPlugin
    }
}
```

I need need to do the same this for Kotlin, but I am stumped as to what plugin to import and apply:

```
import org.gradle.api.plugins.GroovyPlugin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.[what goes here?]
import {our internal Java path}.OurBasePlugin

class OurKotlinPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.plugins.apply OurBasePlugin

        project.plugins.apply [what goes here?]
        project.plugins.apply GroovyPlugin
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinPlatformJvmPlugin` is the class you're looking for. [Here is the example](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-kotlin-plugin/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/netflix/nebula/NebulaKotlinPlugin.kt#L31) where they do a similar thing.

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinPlatformJvmPlugin

class OurKotlinPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.plugins.apply KotlinPlatformJvmPlugin
    }
}
```